# forcing a screen mode to be considered valid?

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr

Hi I have a monitor that doesn't seem to report all the video modes it's capable of. I have been able to trick Ubuntu's display system into believing it's capable of these modes by adding an HDMI splitter and putting a second display on that. When I do that, xrandr reports these modes (which are the two I want to use that are otherwise not listed) and the display works perfectly in either of them:

```
   1280x720      60.00 +  59.94    50.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04
```

I have tried to follow guidance in other questions on this topic, and tried this sequence of commands:

```
cvt 1280 720 60
xrandr --newmode "1280x720_60.00"   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-D-0 1280x720_60.00
```

I would have expected to use xrandr to set the mode after this, but the --addmode command, is rejected with this error:

```
$ xrandr --addmode DVI-D-0 1280x720_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  47
  Current serial number in output stream:  48
```

I get a similar complaint if I try a vertical rate of 59.94 too. I don't know what to try next. Any suggestions? Did I miss something fundamental?

Thanks for any suggestions!